# Como recuperar um item de string-array dentro do layout da minha activity, no caso "xml"?

Tags: java, android

Criei um array de strings em xml na minha pasta strings.xml, agora quero saber como recuperar um item específica de acordo com sua posição, tanto no próprio código fonte do Java e no código XML...

código na pasta strings:

```
<string-array name="string-array">
    <item>item01</item>
    <item>item02</item>
    <item>item03</item>
    <item>item04</item>
    <item>item05</item>
    <item>item06</item>
    <item>item07</item>
    <item>item08</item>
    <item>item09</item>
    <item>item09</item>
</string-array>
```

Gostaria de inserir um destes itens em minha `TextView`.

Comment: Seria mais fácil, para poder dar uma resposta, se colocasse, na pergunta, o *xml* do array de strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os *string-array* devem ser colocados no ficheiro `/res/values/arrays.xml` e não em `/res/values/strings.xml`

Cada elemento do array não deve ser *hard-coded* no array mas sim utilizar uma referência a uma string definida em `/res/values/strings.xml`.

Para explicar vou utilizar um exemplo tirado deste [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-essentials-working-with-strings-and-string-arrays--mobile-7838).

Primeiro defina as *strings* em `/res/values/strings.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string
        name="app_name">Choose Your Own</string>
    <string
        name="race_orc">Orc</string>
    <string
        name="race_elf">Elf</string>
    <string
        name="race_troll">Troll</string>
    <string
        name="race_human">Human</string>
    <string
        name="race_halfling">Halfling</string>
    <string
        name="race_goblin">Goblin</string>
</resources>
```

Depois, usando essas *strings*, defina o array em `/res/values/arrays.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array
        name="races_array">
        <item>@string/race_goblin</item>
        <item>@string/race_orc</item>
        <item>@string/race_elf</item>
        <item>@string/race_human</item>
        <item>@string/race_troll</item>
        <item>@string/race_halfling</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

No java para obter uma referência ao *string-array* use:

```
String[] cRaces = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.races_array);
```

No xml, por exemplo, num *Spinner* pode usá-lo desta forma:

```
<Spinner
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/spinnerOfCharacterRaces"
     android:entries="@array/races_array">
</Spinner>
```

Para aceder a um determinado item do array não irá utilizar o array mas sim a string definida em `/res/values/strings.xml`.
Isto permite utilizar o nome atribuído à string e não um índice.

Por exemplo num botão:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/race_orc" />
```

Ou no java:

```
String race = getResources().getText(R.string.race_orc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode carregar em um array de `Strings`:

```
String[] mArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.string-array);
```

E, para setar, você pode fazer através de uma interecao simples, como:

```
for (String mString : mArray){
    if (mString.equals("texto")){
        mTxtView.setText(mString);
    }
}
```